# undefined method `todo_items' for #<TodoList:0x4528c20>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting this error

```
undefined method `todo_items' for #<TodoList:0x4528c20>
```

In this code:

```
<h1><%= @todo_list.title %></h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/todo_items/index.html.erb</p>

<ul class="todo_items">
  <% @todo_list.todo_items.each do |todo_item| %>
  <li><%= todo_item.content %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

I am new to rails, i am unsure how to debug this error or **where to look for possible issue**. Can anyone guide me on what is the equivalent of `console.log` or `var_dump` in rails.

**Update:**

todo_items_controller.rb

```
class TodoItemsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @todo_list = TodoList.find(params[:todo_list_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you have in your associated controller (probably named todo_items_controller.rb)? To debug there, use Rails.logger.debug @todo_list

Comment: @tirdadc: Here is my associated TodoItemsController.

Comment: What's in class `TodoList`?

Comment: @UriAgassi: you mean the Model.

Comment: yes, what's in that class?

Comment: @UriAgassi: Thanks, got it working. It had has_many  :todo_item and i changed to todo_items it works. Prob that was the issue.

Comment: @theJava Not probably dude, that is what issue was, and hope you got the idea how `associations` works.

Comment: @theJava Consider accepting the answer which suffice your need. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing a has_many association in your TodoList class.

```
has_many :todo_items
```

Assuming you have a TodoItem class with associated db table

Answer (score 1):

On a `TodoList` object you can call

```
obj.todo_itmes
```

only if you have one such association in your `TodoList` model, as

```
has_many :todo_items
```

for better understanding refer [Rails Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

regarding another part of your question

> what is the equivalent of console.log or var_dump in rails.

please refer [debugging in rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html)